# SQL VIEW to the multiple same tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-view

I have 64 tables vith the same structure. I need to find rows count in each table, but I don't want to query each one separately, so I think that create View is clearly...

```
CREATE VIEW globalResults AS
SELECT 'France' as country, count(RC) as complete FROM tableName1 where RC=18
UNION 
SELECT 'UK' as country, count(RC) as complete     FROM tableName2 where RC=18
UNION
SELECT 'Italy' as country, count(RC) as complete  FROM tableName3 where RC=18
UNION
etc...
```

Is there a better solution how to create VIEW?

Comment: RC=18 for each of the query in the where clause? typo?

Comment: Why do you have separate tables for the different countries? (If your stuck with that design, create a view to UNION ALL every table.)

Comment: Identically structured tables is usually a sign that the data model is wrong. Often you'll find items that should have been modelled as *data* (in one or more columns) has instead been modelled as *metadata* (say, embedded in table or column names). Ideally, you *fix* the data model rather than trying to write increasingly convoluted queries (since it's not easy to write a query that mixes querying data and metadata)

Comment: each table is a separate project with big amount other data

Comment: Use ETL task instead to build your reporting data source.

Comment: What are the table names? Perhaps you can write the select once and loop through all the table names

Comment: If you have a single table with a column 'Country' having all the country names. You can select the `Count(RC) group by Country`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using a `view` here.
`union all` is more efficient as `union` will take unnecessary distinct.
Only need column header for first.
Could use `count(*)`.

```
CREATE VIEW globalResults AS
SELECT 'UK' as country, count(*) as complete FROM tableName2 where RC = 18
union all
SELECT 'France',        count(*)             FROM tableName1 where RC = 18
union all
SELECT 'Italy',         count(*)             FROM tableName3 where RC = 18
...
```

You can get table names from `select name from sys.tables where type = 'u';`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the tables are in the form tablename1, tablename2, tablename3 etc, you can iterate through each table with a loop and get all your counts like this:

```
create table #holding (country varchar(max), cnt int)
declare @iterator int = 1 

while @iterator<=64 begin
exec('insert #holding select countryname, count(RC) FROM tableName'+@iterator+'  where RC=18
group by countryname')

set @iterator=@iterator+1
end 

select * from #holding
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is probably above answer to create a `VIEW` with `UNION ALL` between each table so you can query on demand (that's where my upvote went). If you have some mapping of country names to table names, it would be pretty easy to generate that VIEW dynamically.

Just as an alternative if you only need row counts one-time by table, you can use the statistics.

```
SELECT
    OS.name AS SchemaName,
    O.name AS TableName,
    SUM(S.row_count) AS RecordCount
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats S
    INNER JOIN sys.objects O
        ON o.object_id = s.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas OS
        ON OS.schema_Id = o.schema_id
WHERE S.index_id IN (0, 1) -- Ignore non-clustered indexes
    AND O.type = 'U'
    -- Additional filters for your tables of interest
GROUP BY OS.name, O.name
```

To maximize accuracy, perhaps run `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (<myDB>)  WITH COUNT_ROWS` to ensure stats are refreshed before running.

Comment: While a good concept to consider, I believe this does not take into account the `where RC = 18` clause for OP case. Probably this could be modified to work correctly should target tabels have filtered index on them with the same filter condition and targeting those indexes instead?

Comment: You're absolutely right on that RC. I hadn't thought about that. If you could have a partition scheme on the RC=18, then this method could be used for those partitions. Overall, I just wanted to put it out there. As i mentioned, I voted for another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you will want to have some object to query. 
Also, you will want to have tables populated dynamically.

In this case a user defined function with a cursor inside to loop though similar tables is another step over your solution with a statically hardcoded tables in a view

Performance can be terrible though